# Error selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: room is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, api, selenium, automation

I was trying to automate a web based API (haxball api) using python and selenium
there were two steps

1. After visiting https://html5.haxball.com/headless using your browser console <kbd>F12</kbd> button and execute this `var room = window.HBInit({ roomName: 'botts', maxPlayers: 16 });`.
   After executing a captcha will appear we have to solve it manually.
2. After  solving you have to execute another script `room.getPlayerList();` 
   it will return an array back.

When I manually (using browser and console) do both steps, it works perfectly, but when I automate as using the code below (solving captcha manually at the 15 second interval) it is giving an error after the 15 second wait time (7th line).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://html5.haxball.com/headless")
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("var room = window.HBInit({ roomName: 'botts', maxPlayers: 16 });")
time.sleep(15)
driver.execute_script("room.getPlayerList();")
```

The first Javascript executes fine but the second `driver.execute_script("room.getPlayerList();")` gives an error:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: room is not defined"

but both the Javascript commands execute successfully when I enter them through the browser console one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use it only together

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')
driver.execute_script("""
    var foo = 'this is a test';
    console.log(foo);
""")
```

**Update**

but if we want to get our variable in another `execute_script` method we can defined our variables in `window` for example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')
driver.execute_script("""
    window.foo = 'Window variable';
""")

# some code

driver.execute_script("""
    console.log(window.foo);
""")
```

**Output**

```
# In console
Window variable
```

Comment: But the second java script need to be executed after sometime from the first one.

Comment: @Rudy i found a solution, try this

Comment: great this works, hut how can i store i store the output of the second execution to a variable ?

Comment: try this `driver.execute_script(" window.playerList = room.getPlayerList();")`, you can put in `window` haw many variables you want